# I am getting this error "Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure."

Tags: eclipse, selenium, testng

While executing this code, it generates an error for chrome which timed out waiting for driver server to start.

package pkg;

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class ClassLogin {
    private WebDriver driver;
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("www.xyz.com");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`webdriver.chrome.driver` needs to be set to a path to `chromedriver.exe` and not `chrome.exe`.

You may need to download [ChromeDriver - WebDriver for Chrome](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) and then set there system property appropriately.